# Store as string , enum or a another table in SQL database?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

Recently i faced a dilemma regarding what datatype to store in database.

​My table has new field `LastUpdatedBy` which covering different users from different 3rd party integrations.

It can be

- admin from System X
- assistance manager from System Y
- user from the System itself

`LastUpdatedBy` can be useful for simple audit to trace last updated by, but not needed during normal operations. more 3rd party integrations to add later. We have another detailed auditing

I'm thinking to save them as:

- one field, string `LastUpdatedBy` "system_x:username1",
  "system_y:username2"
- two fields, string `LastUpdatedByName` & enum `LastUpdatedBy` (specify which
  system it from)
- create Many to Many tables

May I know which practice is ideal for above scenario? Thanks.

Comment: Well, if you have a large table, you could simply store it as integer. And create a UpdatesDoneBy table with the detailed info.

Comment: `UpdatedBy` can be useful for audit - really, have you thought this through? User 1 - `UPDATE TABLE SET ImportantColumn = Nonsense`. 5 minutes later, User 2 - `UPDATE TABLE SET OtherColumn = OtherColumn + 1`. If you just have a single `UpdatedBy` in your table, who's getting the blame? If you need auditing, create dedicated auditing tables that track *every* change.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever my bad on the details, this is for simple auditing requested by client, we have another dedicated auditing tables.

Comment: Where/how are the users for each type stored? Do they have a unique ID in their sources. Perhaps a variation on your second option with user ID and source type. This can then be used to look up information about a user.

Comment: If you have a full audit and just want the most recent culprit, I'd probably go with a single field. Its not part of the relational model, more of a logging function so I dont think you need to go overboard on it.